# Estimate of incomplete binomial integral

Tags: probability-distributions, inequalities, special-functions, binomial-coefficients, integral-operators

Let $0\le k \le n$. Prove that
$$
n\binom{n}{k}\int_{0}^{\frac{k}{n+1}}t^k(1-t)^{n-k}\,dt \le 1/2.
$$
As far as I know
1) it is proved for $\frac{k}{n+1}\le 1/2$ and 
2) not proved for $1/2 <\frac{k}{n+1}< 1$.
Is it really so?

Comment: The integral is $B_{k/(n+1)}(k+1,n-k+1)$, in the notation of the Wolfram site. Various transformations and identities (though nothing obviously relevant) are cataloged here: http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Beta3/

Comment: @KevinO'Bryant - thank you for the reference. But it is not obvious how to use such transformations.

Comment: No, they don't seem relevant to me, either. But my first step was to track it down and see what was there. I posted the link for the convenience of the next reader.

Comment: Where can one find the proof for $k\le(n+1)/2$?

Comment: I knew of this problem from Prof. Igor Novikov, he also said that proved the first part. I do not know his proof.

Comment: For fixed $\alpha\in(0,1)$ the value is $\frac12+O(n^{-1/2})$ as $n\to\infty$.  The method is to expand the logarithm of the integrand about $t=k/n$. Expanding more carefully with explicit error terms will prove the inequality for large enough $n$.

Comment: I made a miscalculation (switched the signs at one point). So, I am deleting my answer.

Comment: Comments are deleting, deleting, deleting... One by one. So no one will stay here...

Comment: Instead of the deleted answer, I have posted a new one, hoping it's correct.

Comment: I have simplified the proof of the inequality $I_1\le I_2$.

Comment: I have added details for large $n$.

Comment: I have replaced the answer by a much simpler one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following stronger inequality holds for all $k=0,\dots,n$: 
$$
(n+1)\binom{n}{k}\int_{0}^{\frac{k}{n+1}}t^k(1-t)^{n-k}\,dt \le 1/2.
$$
Indeed, the latter inequality means precisely that the median $m$ of the Beta distribution with parameters $a:=k+1\ge1$ and $b:=n-k+1\ge1$ is no less than $\frac{k}{n+1}=\frac{a-1}{a+b-1}$. 
By the well-known "Mode, Median, and Mean Inequalities" for the Beta distribution (see e.g. page 2 in http://arxiv.org/abs/1111.0433v1), 
\begin{equation}
 m\ge\frac{a-1}{a+b-2}\bigwedge\frac{a}{a+b} \ge\frac{a-1}{a+b-1}=\frac{k}{n+1},  
\end{equation}
as desired.

Comment: Great! We can not take $c=1/2$ from the beginning?

Comment: what I do not understand properly. For $k=n$ we may take $c=1/e$. If the reverse induction works the inequality must be true with this constant, $c=1/e$. But it is not so.

Comment: @Sergei : We cannot take $c=1/2$ right away from the beginning, because I can (in the beginning) get $1/2$ only in the limit. But we can take any $c>1/2$ for all large enough $n$, and then by the backward induction get any such $c$ for all $n$. Thus, we get $1/2$ for all $n$.

Comment: @Sergei : For the backward induction to work, it is not enough to have a $c$ just for one value of $k$ (say for $k=n$). We need to have a $c$ for all $k=0,\dots,n$.

Comment: your solution seems to be clever and good. Unfortunately I am too silly for understanding it, but it is my problem... But - it is just an estimate for an integral, let me believe it has a simple calculus solution.

Comment: How estimates for the median leads to the inequality we need? Values are not monotone in $k$. I do understand it for the mode, not for median.

Comment: it seems I catch that. A fine job, thank you!

Comment: a remark. Please note that one case $2k=n,n+1$ is not covered by the cited paper's inequalities with its strict conditions on $a,b$  and has to be considered separately. But it is easy, fortunately.

Comment: @Sergei : In that paper the inequalities between $a$ and $b$ (and between one of them and $1$) are indeed assumed to be strict. However, the "non-strict" case follows then by continuity. Alternatively, one can follow the lines of the original proof and check that the "non-strict" case is actually covered by the proof.